# How to track JNI method from Java to C?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

So I'm trying to reverse engineer an application.

I'm tracking a JNI method called Test_Method that calls a C method from the shared object,

In the shared object, I can see that the method name Test_Method exists, but it doesn't have any cross-reference.

How do I find the method from the shared object that the JNI method from Java is calling to?

Comment: Terminology: C does not have *methods*, it has *functions*.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the native function that a corresponds to particular Java native method is deterministically related to the Java method name, the fully-qualified name of the class in which it resides, and its argument types if it is overloaded.  The specifics are described in [chapter 2 of the JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html), but rather than sorting through that, it might be easier to just use `javac -h` (JDK 8 or later) or the [`javah`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javah.htm) tool (deprecated since JDK 8, but still present at least in JDK 9) to generate it for you, in the form of a C or C++ header file.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the list of exported functions of your DLL or so file. If it doesn't have a number of functions with `Java_com…` prefix, but has `JNI_OnLoad` instead, your native library then uses [RegisterNatives()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5833), and you must find the relevant table of `JNINativeMethod` structures that maps of the native methods to C functions.